# Got Segmentation Fault while launching stable-diffusion-webui/webui.sh

Tags: segmentation-fault, stable-diffusion

I am trying to launch **[stable diffusion web ui](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui)** on **Manjaro Linux**.

My PC Specs: **ACER NITRO 5 AN515-42** with AMD **CPU:Ryzen 5 2500U** and **GPU: AMD Radeon 560X 4GB GDDR5**.
I followed [This Tutorial](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/wiki/Install-and-Run-on-AMD-GPUs#install-on-amd-and-arch-linux) and [This](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/wiki/Install-and-Run-on-AMD-GPUs#automatic-installation)from [AUTOMATIC1111](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111).

then executing this
`(venv) stable-diffusion-webui] $ ./webui.sh`
or
`(venv) stable-diffusion-webui] $ ./webui-py.sh` which contains

```
#!/bin/bash
python launch.py #add arguments here
```

produces this error

```
################################################################
Install script for stable-diffusion + Web UI
Tested on Debian 11 (Bullseye)
################################################################

################################################################
Running on debabrata user
################################################################

################################################################
Repo already cloned, using it as install directory
################################################################

################################################################
Create and activate python venv
################################################################

################################################################
Launching launch.py...
################################################################
Python 3.10.9 (main, Dec 19 2022, 17:35:49) [GCC 12.2.0]
Commit hash: 0cc0ee1bcb4c24a8c9715f66cede06601bfc00c8
Installing requirements for Web UI
Launching Web UI with arguments: 
No module 'xformers'. Proceeding without it.
Loading weights [fe4efff1e1] from /home/debabrata/AI/stable-diffusion-webui/models/Stable-diffusion/stable_diff_1_4.ckpt
Creating model from config: /home/debabrata/AI/stable-diffusion-webui/configs/v1-inference.yaml
LatentDiffusion: Running in eps-prediction mode
DiffusionWrapper has 859.52 M params.
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./webui.sh
```

##### What went wrong and how can I resolve it??

I have tried executing with `--precision full` `--no-half` arguments but same error occured.